# Fill down first row within each cumulative max, with a twist

Tags: r, data.table

I have data ordered by 'date', with some values 'x' and their cumulative maximum 'cmx'. I want to create a column 'max_date' which is the date of the first row within each cumulative max. With a small twist: when there are several 'x' values which are equal to the current cumulative max, a new 'max date' should be selected for each of these rows.

Some data where two different cummax are annotated:

```
d = structure(list(date = structure(c(18690, 18691, 18692, 18693, 18694, 18695, 18696, 18697), class = "Date"),
                   x = c(18, 70, 57, 94, 94, 13, 98, 23),
                   cmx = c(18, 70, 70, 94, 94, 94, 98, 98)),
                   row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
d
#          date  x cmx
# 1: 2021-03-04 18  18
# 2: 2021-03-05 70  70 # first row of cummax 70: select this date for row 2 & 3 
# 3: 2021-03-06 57  70 # 
# 4: 2021-03-07 94  94 # first row of cummax 94
# 5: 2021-03-08 94  94 # x is equal to cummax 94 again! 
# 6: 2021-03-09 13  94 # I.e. row 5 is a 'new' first date to be used for row 5 & 6  
# 7: 2021-03-10 98  98
# 8: 2021-03-11 23  98
```

Thus, desired result:

```
#          date  x cmx   max_date
# 1: 2021-03-04 18  18 2021-03-04 
# 2: 2021-03-05 70  70 2021-03-05
# 3: 2021-03-06 57  70 2021-03-05
# 4: 2021-03-07 94  94 2021-03-07
# 5: 2021-03-08 94  94 2021-03-08
# 6: 2021-03-09 13  94 2021-03-08
# 7: 2021-03-10 98  98 2021-03-10
# 8: 2021-03-11 23  98 2021-03-10
```

I thought I could use `frollapply` but couldn't get the rolling window to look at all previous rows.

Comment: frollapply looks at previous rows by default, unlike zoo's rollapply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cumsum(x == cmx)` to create groups which separate consecutive rows where 'x' equals `cummax(x)`. Within each group, set 'max_date' to first 'date'.

```
d[ , max_date := date[1], by = cumsum(x == cmx)]
d
#          date  x cmx   max_date
# 1: 2021-03-04 18  18 2021-03-04
# 2: 2021-03-05 70  70 2021-03-05
# 3: 2021-03-06 57  70 2021-03-05
# 4: 2021-03-07 94  94 2021-03-07
# 5: 2021-03-08 94  94 2021-03-08
# 6: 2021-03-09 13  94 2021-03-08
# 7: 2021-03-10 98  98 2021-03-10
# 8: 2021-03-11 23  98 2021-03-10
```

---

A second alternative which avoids using `by` (*may* be faster in some situations):

```
d[rowid(cumsum(x == cmx)) == 1, max_date := date]
d[ , max_date := nafill(max_date, type = "locf")]
```

Use `cumsum(x == cmx)` to create groups which separate consecutive rows where 'x' equals `cummax(x)` (otherwise `rowid(cmx)` would have been enough). Use `rowid` to create a counter within groups. For the first row within each group (`rowid == 1`), set 'max_date' to 'date'. Use `nafill` with  'last-observation-carried-forward' to fill `NA` rows.

Comment: Thanks, it worked really well and was vert fast too even over the 2M rows of data I have. I added another question based on the second highest max if you would like to have a look.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535778/locate-the-row-which-corresponds-to-a-second-highest-cumulative-value-in-a-colum>

Comment: Hi - this solution would seem to fit a problem I'm grappling with but with the omission that it does not enable groups; imagine the same data set with athletes competing over different distances - we would want the same results but for each athlete over each distance.  Adding the groups, eg. : d[ , max_date := date[1], .(cumsum(x == cmx), athlete, distance)] does not work.  Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the table to a data frame
2. Find the index with the match function
3. Find the date corresponding to that index
4. Add column containing that max date value

   df <- as.data.frame(dt)

   dfSub <- subset(df, df$cm == max(df$cm))
   dateOfMax <- max(dfSub$date)

   print(dateOfMax)

   max_date <- rep(dateOfMax,nrow(df))
   df <- cbind(df,max_date)

Comment: That just gives me the max over all rows??

Comment: Assuming you are looking for the date of the first max value, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I need the date in a new column, so for each row, the `max_date` column shows the date the max was achieved - it also has to be the last date, not the first.

Comment: The original post says "If it was the case that 2 or more dates have the same value, then only the most recent date needs to be returned"

Comment: Yes and the dates are in order, so the first max value will be the oldest date, I need the most recent date. so if on day 3 day 1 and day 2 both had the same max value, row 3 would show the date from day 2, not day 1 since it is a more recent date

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, but have had a last go at providing a solution (see further update to original)

Comment: In my example `cm` is the cumulative max for all previous rows, not the entire table. So for row 4 the new column `max_date` should be `2021-01-04`, since up to that point it is the max `prev-rating` and then this date is repeated through to rows 5 and 6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229521/discussion-between-reusen-and-midnightdatageek).

Comment: Hi @reusen I took the liberty to update the question with a simpler example, which _may_ have caused a need to update you code. Sorry for any inconvenience, but I did this with the sole intention to make the post more valuable to future visitors. Cheers